# Facebook ignores "Default Activity Privacy" for application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I set my app's Default Activity Privacy to "Everyone", but when showing an auth dialog for installing the app, Facebook ignores this setting and always shows "Friends".

I have tried that with several apps and is still the same.

A bug regarding this case is also reported in this link:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/268481063205627

Default Activity Privacy is described by Facebook here :  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

Can anyone help me with that? Or can you tell me if there is any other way to set the Activity Privacy through PHP code instead?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the user default settings, you can set an Activity Privacy,
but if the user have make any changes (Friends Only), you can't do something for this.

> If the user changes it to Friends, the permission will be updated to
>   friends only. If the user changes that to Public, your app activity
>   will turn into public actions. Possible settings: None, Friends, Me
>   only, or Public. The user can also change the Activity Privacy setting
>   through the Auth Dialog.

Comment: According to Facebook's description (in the link I provided in my question) you can set the Default Activity Privacy to the audience you wish. So, when the user is prompted with the Auth Dialog in order to install the app the selected audience should correspond to what you set.

Comment: I am aware that user can change the audience in that point and afterwards. What I need is the selected audience to be what I set in my Default Activity Privacy and it seems that it doesn't work properly and could be a bug of Facebook.

Comment: It's all about Facebook User Privacy, and must stay like this.

Comment: I agree that is about Privacy! But it makes no sense to give that option to Developers since nothing is gonna change and will always show 'Friends'. That's why I conclude that is probably a bug. Besides that, users are able to change that setting (as you said) any time they want. That option is useful when users want to make something public through the application with their acceptance, this is what I'm trying to achieve here and is important.